# How do I find my httpd.conf file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

**Edit: Anyone who's using MAMP PRO on a Mac running Mac OS X Lion may find it helpful to know that I finally tracked down my httpd.conf file in my personal library at Application Support > appsolute > MAMP PRO > httpd.conf. The reason I couldn't find it with a normal search is that it's a hidden directory. To access it, open Finder, Choose Go > Go To Folder, then type in ~/Library After tracking it down, you may then discover that it's almost impossible to edit your httpd.conf file. ); **

This is a weird one. I'm using MAMP on a Mac and want to modify my httpd.conf file so it defaults my URL's to lower case. So I navigated to Applications > MAMP > conf > apache > httpd.conf and added this line of code:

```
RewriteMap tolower int:tolower
```

I then modified one of my .htaccess files accordingly, but nothing happened. (Yes, I restarted my servers.)

I then reopened my httpd.conf file and added this code, which I understand is supposed to display "verbose" messages in my log file:

```
LogLevel trace8
```

I then opened my log file @ Application > MAMP > logs > apache_error.log. There's code associated with the web pages I most recently visited, but they're just generic messages - not "verbose" messages.

Someone who understands Apache far better than me told me this indicates that the httpd.conf file I modified isn't being used by my server or sites. In other words, there must be another httpd.conf file out there somewhere.

Sure enough, I typed httpd.conf into Apple's finder and found half a dozens files with that name. I don't know where they came from; I recently tried to install Drupal and Aqquia, so that might be where some of them originated.

Anyway, I added the code (including LogLevel trace8) to EVERY httpd.conf file, restarted my servers, and I STILL don't see any changes on my websites, and I still just see generic code in my log file.

I'm completely snowed. It looks like the httpd.conf file in my MAMP folder is out of the loop, yet the Apache log file in the same folder is being used...or can errors be written to more than one Apache log file at the same time?

If I rename the httpd.conf file in my MAMP folder and restart my servers, my sites display fine, further suggesting that this httpd.conf is outside the flow. Yet if I rename a file that sits beside it named mime.types, my web pages don't display.

Anyway, does anyone have any idea how I can figure out what's going on?

If not, then can you advise me on Plan B? If I can't find my httpd.conf file, then I'll have to abandon ship and just do it online. I've found the path to my online httpd.conf file. I don't know how to open online files, but I assume I can copy it to my computer with an ftp program, open it and modify it, then publish it online.

So here are my questions: Am I correct in understanding that I can safely add the code **RewriteMap tolower int:tolower** to my online httpd.conf file without affecting any of my websites UNTIL I also modify a .htaccess file(s)? And if I modify my online config file, do i have to restart the server, just as I do on my computer?

Thanks.

Comment: You found the http.conf file as far as I can tell. The one you mention in the first paragraph works for my MAMP install. Must be something else going on. Are you sure ModRewrite is active for example?

Comment: @ Abhi Becker - Well, my websites are database-driven, with a static page (e.g. MySite/world) that displays dynamic URL's (e.g. MySite/world/arizona or MySite/world/new-york). I added various rules to my .htaccess files, like ErrorDocument 404 /404.php and
RewriteRule ^dictionary/([a-zA-Z0-9$()_/-]+)/?$ dictionary/index.php?dict=$1 [L] So I assume ModRewrite must be active, but I don't really understand how it all works.

Comment: Apache is complicated. I know enough to get buy but even after working with it 10 years I still need help with basic stuff like this. Sorry, i can't help with your problem. But I'm pretty sure you've found the right config file.

Answer (score 9):

First, use the `ps` command to find the full path to the running Apache process:

```
$ ps ax | grep httpd
   28   ??  Ss     3:01.99 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

On this system, Apache is `/usr/sbin/httpd`.

Second, run that binary with the `-V` option to show its configuration. This should include the path to the config file.

```
$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V
...
Server compiled with....
..
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

On this system, the running copy of Apache reads its config from `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Comment: @ Andrew Medico - Thanks, but how do I run that ps command and binary? Where do I paste that code into?

Comment: OK, I Google'd it and learned that I can run the ps command with TextWrangler, so I'm searching my computer now. Hopefully, I can run the "binary" with TextWrangler, too. ;)

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom No... not TextWrangler - it can do basic stuff but doesn't work properly. Use /Applications/Utilities/Terminal. A "$" symbol means "execute this line (excluding the dollar sign) in a terminal emulator".

Comment: @ Abhi Beckert - You mean I should NOT use the $ sign when pasting the code into Terminal? I tried it both ways without success. Just now I deleted the dollar sign, put the code on a single line and eliminated multiple spaces between search terms. This is the result I got: Davids-MacBook-Pro-4:~ MyName$ ps ax | grep httpd 28 ?? Ss 3:01.99 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
grep: unknown devices method
Davids-MacBook-Pro-4:~ MyName$

Comment: Well, I searched for the code with Apache and found a file @ usr/sbin/httpd. When I open it with TextWrangler or TextEdit, I see a bunch of strange characters - like a foreign language. I deleted all the contents, saved it and restarted my servers, but my websites worked normally. (So I pasted the code back and saved it, of course.) When I open it in Terminal, this is all I see:

Last login: Sun Apr  6 17:02:48 on ttys001
Davids-MacBook-Pro-4:~ davidblomstrom$ /usr/sbin/httpd ; exit;
Bus error: 10
logout

[Process completed]

Comment: This is the only answer I've been able to find that worked for RedHat/Centos.